# Simulation issue when using LT3012B

Tags: voltage-regulator, ltspice, energy-harvesting

For an energy havesting application I needed a power management circuit so that it can power a wireless sensor module. The sensor module requires roughly 25mA current in active mode and 100uA in sleep mode. I used the [LT3012B](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3012bf.pdf) which is a low power linear regulator for this. It is given in datasheet that this IC can give 250mA output current but it is not happening in simulation. I want capacitor C4 to discharge through the transistor when it crosses 6V and power the IC . Why is output voltage different from a constant dc voltage?

asc code

```
    Version 4
SHEET 1 3448 680
WIRE 976 -32 656 -32
WIRE 976 32 976 -32
WIRE 976 144 976 96
WIRE 976 144 896 144
WIRE 1152 144 976 144
WIRE 1168 144 1152 144
WIRE 1328 144 1232 144
WIRE 1536 144 1328 144
WIRE 896 160 896 144
WIRE 976 160 976 144
WIRE 656 176 656 -32
WIRE 1152 176 1152 144
WIRE 1536 176 1536 144
WIRE 1328 208 1328 144
WIRE 1760 224 1600 224
WIRE 896 288 896 224
WIRE 976 288 976 224
WIRE 656 304 656 256
WIRE 1152 304 1152 240
WIRE 1232 304 1152 304
WIRE 1328 304 1328 272
WIRE 1328 304 1232 304
WIRE 1536 320 1536 272
WIRE 1696 320 1536 320
WIRE 1856 320 1696 320
WIRE 2320 320 2144 320
WIRE 2560 320 2320 320
WIRE 1232 336 1232 304
WIRE 2560 336 2560 320
WIRE 1696 400 1696 384
WIRE 2560 400 2560 384
WIRE 2320 416 2320 400
WIRE 2320 416 2144 416
WIRE 2320 480 2320 416
WIRE 2000 528 2000 480
WIRE 2320 624 2320 560
FLAG 656 304 0
FLAG 976 288 0
FLAG 896 288 0
FLAG 2000 528 0
FLAG 2320 624 0
FLAG 2560 400 0
FLAG 1232 336 0
FLAG 1760 288 0
FLAG 1696 400 0
SYMBOL voltage 656 160 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 24 124 Left 2
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=100
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 311 60)
SYMBOL cap 960 32 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 30pF
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0.1
SYMBOL cap 880 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 30pF
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0.1
SYMBOL cap 960 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 30pF
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0.1
SYMBOL diode 1168 160 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMBOL diode 1168 240 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMBOL cap 1312 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 100n
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=2
SYMBOL PowerProducts\\LT3012B 2000 352 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL res 2304 304 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 750K
SYMBOL res 2304 464 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 249K
SYMBOL cap 2544 320 R0
SYMATTR InstName C6
SYMATTR Value 3.3µ
SYMBOL pnp 1600 272 R180
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value 2N3906
SYMBOL zener 1776 288 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value EDZV6_2B
SYMBOL cap 1680 320 R0
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMATTR Value 1µ
TEXT 624 328 Left 2 !.tran 0 1 0 uic
TEXT 1016 424 Left 2 !.model d d ron=1 roff=1g vfwd=0.45 vrev=1k
```

[image: Output observed in LTSpice]

Comment: The part in question is the LT3012B.

Comment: Look at the voltage waveform at the emitter - use your brain.

Comment: Is this meant to harvest energy from the wall plug?

Comment: @Andyaka i tried i'm not getting it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen yes i'm just conducting some simulation studies

Comment: @Hyde - test other nodes and analyse - you have the models and the circuit and the simulation tool. What do I have?